# Django 1.8 Why local static requests raise 404?

Tags: django

Project name is `exam`. I place `simple.css` file in `exam/static/css/`. When I request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/simple.css`, it returns 404 error, saying `'css\simple.css' could not be found`. The settings seem all right. In production environment the static requests are all right with nginx.

Related infomation:

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))).replace('\\','/')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\','/')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static").replace('\\','/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:

)

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL , document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

Comment: ermm shouldn't the url be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/exam/css/simple.css`?

Comment: @Lim H I tried, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're missing the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting.

When in production, `python manage.py collectstatic` moves all static files inside `STATIC_ROOT` directory so `nginx` can look up here for them, however in dev mode, django needs to know where the static files are, and use `STATICFILES_DIRS` tuple for that.

If you have these files inside exam/static, your `STATICFILES_DIRS` should looks like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

Comment: It worked. Actually, first it raise error `The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting`, then I comment `STATIC_ROOT` and everything goes fine. Seems `STATIC_ROOT` is unnecessary in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ./manage runserver  then you're missing STATICFILES_DIRS.

For nginx/gunicorn http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/. Also Django White Noise